# C# program to replicate slide content in one .pptx file to another one

Tags: c#, powerpoint, diagram

I have to copy the contents (content can be text image or drawings) from slides in a source pptx file to a destination pptx file. I cant copy the slide since the destination file has a different theme. I just need to copy the contents to destination file.

Can some one help me on this? I could find some ways to access the text content but couldnt find a way to access image and drawings . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBAspeak, it'd be something like this, assuming a reference to the two slides in oSldSource and oSldTarget:

```
Dim oSh as Shape 
For Each oSh in oSldSource.Shapes
  .Copy
  oSldTarget.Shapes.Paste
Next
```

What'll likely happen is that any shape whose fill/line/whatever color is assigned one of the theme colors in oSldSource will assume the corresponding theme color when it lands in oSrcTarget.  So you might want to pick up the shape's RGB color before copying, then assign it back after pasting.  That'll assign a fixed color rather than a flexible theme color to the shape.